# How to stop this memory leak

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am learning pointers in C++ and am working on the new and delete functionality . 
I have a local function which allocates memory on the heap but because i am returning the 2d array that i have created , I dont understand how to plug this memory leak, any help would be appreciated

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "integers.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i[]={1,2,3,4};
int n=sizeof(i)/sizeof(int);
cout<<n<<endl;
printint(genarr(i,n),n);
}
```

integers.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int** genarr(int* val,int n)
{
int i,j;
int **a=new int*[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
a[i]=new int[n];

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
if(i==j)
a[i][j]=val[i];

return a; // The variable that will leak but because i am returning it , how do stop it
}

void printint(int** a,int n){
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
    cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
   }
cout<<endl;
}
return ;
}
```

integers.h

```
int** genarr(int*val, int n);
void printint(int **a,int n);
```

compiled by

```
g++ main.cpp integers.cpp -o integers
```

I have heard about smart pointers and am planning to learn about them after this , but for now i want to know if there is way to fix this or should i just go for smart pointers ?

Comment: My recommendation is that you don't use pointers at all, and instead use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or for compile-time fixed arrays use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)).

Comment: Just make the variable "a" as global variable

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is my method not standard practice or is there some inherent issue with it? I am learning pointers for now and dont want to use vectors.

Comment: Well as you noticed it might be very hard to do proper management of the memory when using pointers. Smart pointers can alleviate some of that, but I rather recommend you look at them form an *ownership* perspective rather than simple "self-deleting pointers" or an alternative to garbage-collection. The "proper" way is to use [the standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) as much as possible.

Comment: @akshay while that will work for sure , declaring values global seems more like a short-cut , is there a more definite approach here that allows me to do this?

Comment: @akshay No, global variables are almost *never* the solution to any problem. Global variables are generally bad.

Comment: @akshay - Please put that terrible suggestion in the answer section where it may be downvoted accordingly. Or are you circumventing SO's quality control intentionally?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Here, you need the access to the variable "a" even after the genarr function returns. So, you need to make it global. Else you can also include the functionality of printint() function inside the genarr itself at least for the part of code you have shared. As I am seeing the entire array is needed for the printint to work.

Comment: @akshay There's no need to access the `a` variable itself, just its value. And that value is already returned by the function, so it's accessible to its caller just fine.

Comment: @melpomene But when the function returns actually doesn't the local variables get destroyed?

Comment: @akshay So what? As I said, we don't care about `a` itself, only its value. Otherwise `printint` wouldn't work in the existing code anyway.

Comment: If you `new` something, you are responsible to `delete` it.  Likewise, if you `new[]` something you are responsible to `delete[]` it.  In modern C++, with smart pointers and containers and move semantics, even on large programs, I've not needed to use those constructs.  I could use them, just haven't been necessary -- however, they're available when needed for a given context where they are the right tool to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the problem, you need to `delete` what you `new`'d.

Change the code in `main` to:

```
int **arr = genarr(i,n);
printint(arr,n);
// we're done using arr; now we need to free it
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    delete[] arr[j];
delete[] arr;
```

---

You can also extend `integers.cpp` and add a `delarr` function that complements `genarr`:

```
void delarr(int **a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        delete[] a[i];
    }
    delete[] a;
}
```

Then `main` becomes simply:

```
int **arr = genarr(i,n);
printint(arr,n);
delarr(arr,n);
```

Comment: Might also be worth adding a `delarr` function to complement `genarr`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to avoid memory leaks in C++ is to avoid explicitly calling `delete` anywhere.  Smart pointers can solve this for you.

In your specific case, you could try something like this (untested):

```
using Vector = unique_ptr<int[]>;
using Matrix = unique_ptr<Vector[]>;

Matrix genarr(const int* val, int n)
{
    Matrix a(new Vector[n]);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        a[i].reset(new int[n]);

    // ...
```